# Why is my Gitlab-CI service failing on some runners?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, paketo

I'm using `Gitlab-CI` to build my application and have a weird error on some runners (Docker executors) when my service is starting. Indeed, on some runners, the service crashes at startup with a `ClassNotFoundException`, and works perfectly on others runners.

This is the part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` which is relevant :

```yaml
mvn-build:
  services:
    - name: my-repository.com:5002/networklocation/configuration-api:1.0.23
      alias: configuration
      variables:
        CNB_PLATFORM_API: ""
        SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker
```

This `configuration-api` application is a Java Spring Boot application built with [Paketo Cloud Native Buildpacks](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot).

Here are the logs when the job is scheduled on a non-working runner :

```
[service:configuration-api] 2023-02-23T08:30:33.319822839Z Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
[service:configuration-api] 2023-02-23T08:30:33.320160182Z Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

The only workaround I have found is to connect to the runner and do a `docker volume prune`. After that operation, the service is working correctly for some time, until a new build breaks it on some runners.

All runners are configured as docker executors and are in the same version (currently 15.8.1)

One hypothesis I have is that [Cloud Native Buildpacks creates image without timestamp](https://buildpacks.io/docs/features/reproducibility/), may this cause some issues ? Is there anything else that may cause this issue ?

Comment: If a prune fix the problem, could it be your runner host runs out of disk space after a while and thus not pull the complete image/all layers for this service ?

Comment: No, I checked and it seems that the runners are not full at all

Comment: One way to ensure the image is ok could be to use the image tag (on top of the version) as explained [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#use-checksum-to-keep-your-image-secure). Something like `my-repository.com:5002/networklocation/configuration-api:1.0.23@sha256:......`

Comment: Yes, I tried that too to ensure it's the correct image, and it is.

Comment: Have you tried disabling cache volumes in your runner configuration?

Comment: No, because these runners are shared runners and belong to my company. We made a debuging session with the shared runners owners, that's why I know disk is not full and that pruning volume "solve" the problem, but I can't ask them to change the runner configuration just for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the root cause of the issue, unfortunately I didn't provide enough details on the questions for someone to resolve the issue.

The problem was that my `configuration-api` image, which is used as a `Gitlab-CI` service was build with `CNB buildpacks` by calling the [lifecycle endpoint](https://github.com/buildpacks/lifecycle). The final Docker image was created with a  directory structure of `/builds/` because `CNB_APP_DIR` was set to this value. In fact, the underlying issue is that [it's not possible to decorelate source and target folders with CNB lifecycle](https://github.com/buildpacks/lifecycle/issues/1034).

The unintended consequence was that by using this image as a `Gitlab-CI` service, it conflicted with the volume created by `Gitlab-CI`.

I fix this issue by recreating my `configuration-api` with a `CNB_APP_DIR` of `/workspace`. I did that by copying my `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` to the `workspace` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Build it with maven debug enabled and simply see the difference.
There is some difference in java version / maven version / dependency resolution (for project or for plugins) that you haven't found.

As a debug step dump dependency tree before the real build (mvn -X  dependency:tree) and store it job artifact and compare between working and nonworking builds.